# ansible different sections, different hosts same playbook

Tags: ansible, devops

I have a use case where I need to do a task (reissue ssl certs). The steps go like this:

- open port on CA server
- generate cert on normal server, which contacts the CA
- close port on the CA server

This means that I have a playbook that looks like this:

```
- name: open port
  hosts: caserver
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: open firewall
      iptables: chain=FWR protocol=tcp source={{ item }} destination_port=8888 jump=ACCEPT state=present
      with_inventory_hostnames: WHAT IS HERE???

- name: generate ssl certificate
  hosts: all:!caserver
  become: yes
  roles:
    - sslcert

- name: close port
  hosts: caserver
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: close firewall
      iptables: chain=FWR protocol=tcp source={{ item }} destination_port=8888 jump=ACCEPT state=absent
      with_inventory_hostnames: WHAT IS HERE???
```

Then I would call this from the command line using limits to control what machines get re-issued.

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts -l myserver,caserver -c ssh --ask-vault-pass -K generate_certs.yml
```

The problem is that I am not opening up that port on the caserver.

I have been trying some of the [magic variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts) and no luck.

I am thinking I have to create a group in the `hosts` file and then use that. So I'd make a group, re-issue and then remove them from that group.

I'd like not to do that shuffle is there a better way in ansible?

Comment: Do you mind specifying what your problem is? Hostname resolution? Inventory file definition? Other? You posted no relevant information at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [delegation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation).

```
- name: generate ssl certificate
  hosts: all:!caserver
  become: yes

  pre_tasks:
    - name: open firewall
      iptables: chain=FWR protocol=tcp source={{ inventory_hostname }} destination_port=8888 jump=ACCEPT state=present
      delegate_to: caserver

  roles:
    - sslcert

  tasks:
    - name: close firewall
      iptables: chain=FWR protocol=tcp source={{ inventory_hostname }} destination_port=8888 jump=ACCEPT state=absent
      delegate_to: caserver
```